# Azure databricks: Problem saving to csv with +100 columns and many nulls, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have seen many ppl having this issue but none of those were able to resolve my issue. I have a json file that I read in as a spark dataframe and then flatten it. Lastly, I try to save the flatten file as a csv with +100 columns and >47 million rows and many nulls.

I get the error `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.`
Here is part of the stack trace:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 41.0 (TID 164) (10.139.64.7 executor 22): java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.recordWriteFailure$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$12(FileFormatWriter.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$4(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1696)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:905)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: BMH.reinvoke=Lambda(a0:L/SpeciesData<LLL>,a1:L,a2:L,a3:L,a4:L,a5:L,a6:L,a7:L,a8:L,a9:L,a10:L,a11:L)=>{
    t12:L=BoundMethodHandle$Species_L3.argL2(a0:L);
    t13:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(t12:L,a2:L);
    t14:L=BoundMethodHandle$Species_L3.argL1(a0:L);
    t15:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(t14:L,a1:L);
    t16:L=MethodHandleImpl.array(a4:L,a5:L,a6:L,a7:L,a8:L,a9:L,a10:L,a11:L);
    t17:L=BoundMethodHandle$Species_L3.argL0(a0:L);
    t18:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(t17:L,t15:L,t13:L,a3:L,t16:L);t18:L}
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:127)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:660)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.prepare(LambdaForm.java:635)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.<init>(MethodHandle.java:461)
    at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle.<init>(BoundMethodHandle.java:58)
    at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Species_L3.<init>(Species_L3)
    at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Species_L3.make(Species_L3)
    at java.lang.invoke.BoundMethodHandle$Species_LL.copyWithExtendL(Species_LL)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.makePairwiseConvertByEditor(MethodHandleImpl.java:231)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.makePairwiseConvert(MethodHandleImpl.java:194)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.makePairwiseConvert(MethodHandleImpl.java:380)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.asTypeUncached(MethodHandle.java:776)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.asType(MethodHandle.java:761)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl$AsVarargsCollector.asTypeUncached(MethodHandleImpl.java:508)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.asType(MethodHandle.java:761)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:323)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

22/12/13 09:56:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 41.0 (TID 165) (10.139.64.5, executor 23, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, taskResourceAssignments Map())
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221213083124-0000/22 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 50)
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20221213083124-0000/22 removed: Command exited with code 50
22/12/13 09:56:12 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 22 on 10.139.64.7: Command exited with code 50
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20221213083124-0000/25 on worker-20221213085244-10.139.64.7-41835 (10.139.64.7:41835) with 4 core(s)
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 22 (epoch 18)
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20221213083124-0000/25 on hostPort 10.139.64.7:41835 with 4 core(s), 3.1 GiB RAM
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 22 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(22, 10.139.64.7, 40355, None)
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 22 successfully in removeExecutor
22/12/13 09:56:12 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221213083124-0000/25 is now RUNNING
22/12/13 09:56:15 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.139.64.6:55600) with ID 24,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/12/13 09:56:15 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:16 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.139.64.6:39649 with 1504.5 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(24, 10.139.64.6, 39649, None)
22/12/13 09:56:16 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_36_piece0 in memory on 10.139.64.5:45187 (size: 220.5 KiB, free: 1504.3 MiB)
22/12/13 09:56:18 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:18 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 10.139.64.5:45187 (size: 18.1 KiB, free: 1504.3 MiB)
22/12/13 09:56:21 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:22 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.139.64.7:55476) with ID 25,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.139.64.7:43527 with 1504.5 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(25, 10.139.64.7, 43527, None)
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO DataSourceFactory$: DataSource Jdbc URL: jdbc:mariadb://consolidated-westeuropec2-prod-metastore-1.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/organization8773400708728304?useSSL=true&sslMode=VERIFY_CA&disableSslHostnameVerification=true&trustServerCertificate=false&serverSslCert=/databricks/common/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.crt
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Starting...
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Start completed.
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Shutdown initiated...
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Shutdown completed.
22/12/13 09:56:24 INFO MetastoreMonitor: Metastore healthcheck successful (connection duration = 207 milliseconds)
22/12/13 09:56:27 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:27 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_35_piece0 in memory on 10.139.64.5:45187 (size: 13.6 KiB, free: 1504.3 MiB)
22/12/13 09:56:30 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:33 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:34 INFO DriverCorral: DBFS health check ok
22/12/13 09:56:34 INFO HiveMetaStore: 1: get_database: default
22/12/13 09:56:34 INFO audit: ugi=root  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
22/12/13 09:56:34 INFO DriverCorral: Metastore health check ok
22/12/13 09:56:36 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:39 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:42 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:45 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:48 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:51 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:54 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:56:57 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:57:00 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:57:03 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:57:06 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:57:08 INFO CommChannelWebSocket: onWebSocketConnect: websocket connected with session: WebSocketSession[websocket=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.CommChannelWebSocket@e83bc3c],behavior=SERVER,connection=WebSocketServerConnection@52d196e1::DecryptedEndPoint@685a7d89{l=/10.139.64.4:6062,r=/10.139.0.4:51020,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=2/7200000},remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@486edc7e[batching=true],incoming=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.CommChannelWebSocket@e83bc3c],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerConnection]]
22/12/13 09:57:08 ERROR OutgoingDirectNotebookMessageBuffer: Session should be closed before interrupting.
22/12/13 09:57:08 INFO OutgoingDirectNotebookMessageBuffer: Stop MessageSendTask with session: 1914687926
22/12/13 09:57:08 INFO OutgoingDirectNotebookMessageBuffer: Start MessageSendTask with session: 349608004
22/12/13 09:57:08 INFO CommChannelWebSocket: onWebSocketClose: websocket closed with statusCode: 1006, reason: Disconnected
22/12/13 09:57:09 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 1, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 1.0 
22/12/13 09:57:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 23 successfully in removeExecutor
22/12/13 09:57:32 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 6535aa05-18e2-43f7-83e5-bbcf56a1ee02.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 41.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 41.0 (TID 165) (10.139.64.5 executor 23): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 23 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 52
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3235)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3235)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1424)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3524)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3462)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3450)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$runJob$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1169)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2713)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:299)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(QueryExecution.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$withMVTagsIfNecessary(QueryExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:430)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:956)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/12/13 09:57:32 INFO ClusterLoadMonitor: Removed query with execution ID:9. Current active queries:0
22/12/13 09:57:32 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221213083124-0000/26 is now RUNNING
22/12/13 09:57:32 WARN JupyterDriverLocal: User code returned error with traceback: [0;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------[0m
[0;31mPy4JJavaError[0m                             Traceback (most recent call last)
[0;32m<command-3309668900398459>[0m in [0;36m<cell line: 268>[0;34m()[0m
[1;32m    266[0m [0;34m[0m[0m
[1;32m    267[0m [0m_type[0m [0;34m=[0m [0;34m"orderState"[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0;32m--> 268[0;31m [0mcheck_if_dupe[0m[0;34m([0m[0m_type[0m[0;34m,[0m [0myear[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mmonth[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mday[0m[0;34m,[0m [0myear_prev[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mmonth_prev[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mday_prev[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0m[1;32m    269[0m [0;31m#display(df)[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[1;32m    270[0m [0;31m#check_df(df, _type)[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m

[0;32m<command-3309668900398459>[0m in [0;36mcheck_if_dupe[0;34m(_type, year, month, day, year_prev, month_prev, day_prev)[0m
[1;32m    235[0m     [0mdf_flattened[0m [0;34m=[0m [0mdf_flattened[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mna[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mfill[0m[0;34m([0m[0mvalue[0m[0;34m=[0m[0;36m0[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0;32m/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py[0m in [0;36mget_return_value[0;34m(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)[0m
[1;32m    324[0m             [0mvalue[0m [0;34m=[0m [0mOUTPUT_CONVERTER[0m[0;34m[[0m[0mtype[0m[0;34m][0m[0;34m([0m[0manswer[0m[0;34m[[0m[0;36m2[0m[0;34m:[0m[0;34m][0m[0;34m,[0m [0mgateway_client[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[1;32m    325[0m             [0;32mif[0m [0manswer[0m[0;34m[[0m[0;36m1[0m[0;34m][0m [0;34m==[0m [0mREFERENCE_TYPE[0m[0;34m:[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0;32m--> 326[0;31m                 raise Py4JJavaError(
[0m[1;32m    327[0m                     [0;34m"An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n"[0m[0;34m.[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[1;32m    328[0m                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

[0;31mPy4JJavaError[0m: An error occurred while calling o3023.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:334)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(QueryExecution.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$withMVTagsIfNecessary(QueryExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:186)
    ... 49 more

22/12/13 09:57:32 INFO ProgressReporter$: Removed result fetcher for 3479767264321116845_5405572452950350648_76aea015601745f79d10ebdb188a0ee2
22/12/13 09:57:33 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 0, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 0.85 
22/12/13 09:57:36 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 0, Old Ema: 0.85, New Ema: 0.0 
22/12/13 09:57:40 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.139.64.5:50180) with ID 26,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/12/13 09:57:42 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.139.64.5:44301 with 1504.5 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(26, 10.139.64.5, 44301, None)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221213083124-0000/25 is now DECOMMISSIONED (worker decommissioned because of kill request from HTTP endpoint (data migration disabled))
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Asked to decommission executor app-20221213083124-0000/25
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Decommission executors: 25
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Mark BlockManagers (BlockManagerId(25, 10.139.64.7, 43527, None)) as being decommissioning.
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Notify executor 25 to decommissioning.
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20221213083124-0000/25 decommissioned: ExecutorDecommissionInfo(worker decommissioned because of kill request from HTTP endpoint (data migration disabled),Some(10.139.64.7),false)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221213083124-0000/25 is now LOST (worker lost)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20221213083124-0000/25 removed: worker lost
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Master removed worker worker-20221213085244-10.139.64.7-41835: 10.139.64.7:41835 got disassociated
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Worker worker-20221213085244-10.139.64.7-41835 removed: 10.139.64.7:41835 got disassociated
22/12/13 09:58:28 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 25 on 10.139.64.7: Executor decommission: worker decommissioned because of kill request from HTTP endpoint (data migration disabled)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 25 (epoch 18)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Handle removed worker worker-20221213085244-10.139.64.7-41835: 10.139.64.7:41835 got disassociated
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 25 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(25, 10.139.64.7, 43527, None)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 25 successfully in removeExecutor
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Shuffle files lost for host: 10.139.64.7 (epoch 18)
22/12/13 09:58:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Shuffle files lost for worker worker-20221213085244-10.139.64.7-41835 on host 10.139.64.7
```

I have tried to increase the driver memory without any success and switching to a higher performer cluster without any success.

Comment: Can you try setting an option while writing as `df.write.option("maxColumnsInMemory",200)` and try?

Comment: it did not work

Comment: Can you just add a code snippet of how you are reading, transformation json and trying to save that, so that someone can reproduce it and help you.. 100 columns should not be an issue unless there is something in your code that is behaving weirdly.

Comment: I need to check if I can simplify my code somehow. 100 columns is maybe not a problem but how about with 47million rows as well?